# Can htaccess redirect to parent folder?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My domain is in my user folder. I would like to serve a file from another folder down a level, under the same user. I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^test$ ../testfolder/test.txt [L]
```

But Apache serves a 400 Bad Request. Is htaccess capable of dropping down a level like this?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this code to dynamically figure out `PARENT` directory and then rewrite to that:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# dynamically figure out parent directory using composite RewriteCond
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)/[^/]+/\1$
RewriteRule .* - [E=PARENT:%2]

RewriteRule ^test$ %{ENV:PARENT}/test.txt [L,NC]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s60POT/1)

Comment: anubhava I read that htaccess would not redirect outside the document root, so I just used chdir() in a php script. Thank you for the reply though, it looks very clever.

Comment: This is not at all redirecting to outside doc root. It is for rewriting from `/project/usr/test` to `/project/test.txt` where is `/project` is a sub directory of site root